# Solving Trig Problem - A Level Maths

Tags: trigonometry

Question: An equation of a curve is $y = \cos 2x + 2\sin x$. Find $dy/dx$ and the coordinates of the stationary points from $0 < x < \pi$.

I got as far as $-2\cos x = -4\sin x\cos x$
Surely now I can divide by $\cos x$ to get:
$-2 = -4\sin x$, hence $0.5 = \sin x$ and so on...

But apparently this is wrong? The answer is $\cos x(-2\sin x + 1) = 0$ meaning $\sin x$ is $0.5$ AND $\cos x = 0$.

What is wrong with my method? Why does my method not also get the $\cos x = 0$ part?

Thanks!

Comment: Meaning $\sin x=0.5$ **OR** $\cos x=0$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $y=\cos (2x) + 2\sin (x)$ is just $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\sin(2x)+2\cos(x)$$ and the stationary points are at $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, which gives $\sin(2x)=\cos(x)$, *i.e.*, $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\cos(x)$.

Note that you can't cancel the $\cos(x)$ since it could be zero for $x\in (0, \pi)$.

Thus $\cos(x)(2\sin(x)-1)=0$. This is the case when $\cos(x)=0$ or $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$, so when $x=\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{5\pi}{6}$.

The coordinates are then easy to find by substituting these $x$ values back into $y$: $(\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac32), (\frac{\pi}{2}, 1), (\frac{5\pi}{6}, \frac32)$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is simply
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\sin(2x)+2\cos (x)$$
Setting this zero gives
$$2\sin x\cos x=\cos x$$
$$\cos(x)(1-2\sin (x))=0$$
Now you can't cancel $\cos x$ as it can be zero..and division by zero is not defined
SO the answers are...$\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You haven't taken into consideration the possibility that $\cos(x) =0$ as if it was you would be dividing by zero when you are going from $-2\cos(x) = -4\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to $-2 = -4\sin(x)$. Remember dividing by zero is ILLEGAL!

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you can't divide by $\cos{x}$ if it is zero. Rearranging $ -2\sin{x}=-4\sin{x}\cos{x} $ gives $\cos{x}(2\sin{x}-1)=0$.

I think you have a related issue in your assertion that this now means $\cos{x}=0$ and $\sin{x}=1/2$ (or at least, are being confusingly imprecise): if $ab=0$, this means one of the following is true:

- $a=0$ (and $b \neq 0$),
- $b=0$ (and $a \neq 0$),
- $a=0$ and $b=0$.

(since "any number times zero is zero") Hence the condition $\cos{x}(2\sin{x}-1)=0$ includes:

- $x$ where $\cos{x}=0$
- $x$ where $\sin{x}=1/2$

(and it happens in this case that these cannot both be true for the same $x$).